# Homework Method Return Assistance

Tags: java

I have been working on this problem for days now and I still have not been able to figure it out. If anyone can help that would be great.

the problem goes...
Write a program that computes a single filer’s income tax burden.

```
TAX RATE   Single Filers Income
10%        Up to $6000
15%        $6,001 - $27,950
27%        $27,951 - $67,700
30%        $67,701 - $141,250
35%        $141,251 - $307,050
38.6%      $307, 051 or more
```

- The user should be able input her income using new Scanner (System.in), input method and then be returned the amount of tax owed.
- All source code for solving the problem and handling user input should be created in a “programmer created class.”
- Use return for retrieving all values from calculations or if/else statements etc.
- main will be used to operate the program.
- Output should have proper formatting for dollars, 2 decimal places.

Sample Output (Output should have proper formatting for dollars, 2 decimal places)

> Income tax for a single person making $85000.00 is $25500.00
>
> Income tax for a single person making $9800.00 is $1470.00

I get a lot of error messages here i'm sure I have a lot to fix. All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

This is what I have so far. Not sure if I am going in the correct direction with this.

```
package taxscan12;
import java.util.Scanner;

class tax{
    double income, taxrate, math;
 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   
    tax tax1 = new tax();
    
    double tax1(){
        tax1.income = scan.nextDouble();
        if(income <= 6000){
            taxrate = .10;
            System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");
            return math = income * taxrate;
        }

        if(income >= 6001 && income <= 27950 ){
            taxrate = .15; 
            System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");
            return math = income * taxrate;
        }
       
        if(income >= 27951 && income <= 67700){
            taxrate = .27;
            System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");
            return math = income * taxrate;
        }

        if(income >= 67701 && income <= 141250){
            taxrate = .30;
            System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");
            return math = income * taxrate; 
        }

        if(income >= 141251 && income <= 307050){
            taxrate = .35;
            System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");
            return math = income * taxrate;
        }

        if(income >= 307051){
            taxrate = .386;
            System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");
            return math = income * taxrate;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Taxscan12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double taxes;
        tax taxx = new tax();
        taxes = taxx.tax1();
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice - get it working a little at a time.  Write a very small program that meets just one of the requirements of the final program.  Get it working completely.  Then add code to implement another requirement.  And so on until it's all done.  Don't write pages of code then start to wonder whether it will work or not.

Comment: Incidentally, did your professor tell you to use `double` as the data type for the dollar amounts?  Or did he/she teach you about `BigDecimal`?

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that the `tax` class has a field of type `tax`, which means the JVM will overflow the stack the first time it tries to instantiate one.  Do like @DavidWallace said, and start by writing a very simple program that does one thing, does it correctly, and has no extra cruft.  Then add functionality.

Comment: Also, having a method and a field with the same name is going to bite you on the butt.

Comment: Also, tax rates are incremental (at least in the U.S.). So someone making $7000 won't pay 15% on the whole $7000.  They'll pay 10% on the first $6000, then 15% on the next $1000.  Your current logic is calculating the tax rate on the entire income based on the bracket.

Comment: @azurefrog, While this is true, this probably isn't relevant. The user mentioned that this is homework, and homework problems are often simplified to make things easier. Based on the table given, the problem probably isn't expecting real US tax liability values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've loaded your program into my IntelliJ window, and I've just gone through phase by phase looking at ways you can fix/improve your program. I'm going to try to cover a lot, and I'm going to include some things which might be *optional*, i.e. things that you wouldn't need to do to get your program to work but probably should be doing.

**Use care when declaring fields**

In your `tax` class, you declare the field `tax tax1 = new tax();` This will cause your program to have what is known as a `StackOverflowError`. If you're in computer science, you'll learn more about what this actually means, but it essentially means your code is running forever and causing the 'stack' to run out of memory. Why is this happening? Every time you create a new instance of your `tax` class by calling `new tax()`, your code tries to create a new instance of `tax` by calling `new tax()` in the line that says `tax tax1 = new tax();`. Every time it tries to create a `tax`, it gets stuck because it tries to create another `tax`, and winds up doing this forever. Fortunately, your `tax` class does not need this `tax tax1 = new tax()` line, so we can fix this problem by simply deleting the line `tax tax1 = new tax()` from your `tax` class.

**Use care to refer to your instance's fields, rather than another instances fields**

In your method `double tax1()`, you're referring to fields on your `tax tax1` field you made earlier. Fortunately you don't have to do this. From inside of your `tax` class, you can refer to all of the fields you created by name, e.g. inside of `tax`, you can simply say `income = scan.nextDouble();`

**Print a prompt before scanning for user input**

When you're scanning the command line for user input, such as in your code, it's always a good idea to print out a prompt to the command line before scanning. This way, the user knows they should be entering something rather than just thinking the programming is taking a really long time to run/not doing anything.

You might consider adjusting the first part of your `double tax1()` method to look like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter your income: ");
income = scan.nextDouble();
```

...instead of just `income = scan.nextDouble();`. This way, the user will know that they need to enter their income.

**Avoid doing too many things in one class**

In your `tax` class, you try to calculate the tax and print it to the screen in the same step. Instead, you should use the `double tax1()` method only for calculating the income, and print the result in the `Taxscan12` class's `public static void main(String[] args)` method. This way, it's easier to tell what's going on with your `tax1()` method's calculations and easier to change things later on.

You should remove all of the `System.out.printf(" tax burden is $%.2f ");` lines from your `double tax1()` method in your `tax` class, and adjust your `public static void main(String[] args)` method in your `Taxscan12` class to look more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double taxes;
    Tax taxx = new Tax();
    taxes = taxx.tax1();
    System.out.printf("Your tax burden is $%.2f \n", taxes);
}
```

***Note: *** I added `taxes` as an argument to the `System.out.printf()` call so that the system knows what to print as their tax burden. `%.2f` tells the call to expect a number to go in that spot, but if you don't give it a number it can't print what you told it to print, so it throws an exception.

***If you've been following along up to here, your program should now be working. These next suggestions are a good idea to make your program cleaner, which is an especially good idea if your homework is graded partially on clean code or following conventions***

**Follow Java naming conventions**

The name of your tax class is `tax`, lowercase. This means that to declare an instance of `tax`, you have to do things like `tax taxx = new tax();` 'taxx' isn't a very good name, but I understand why you did it. Because you named your class `tax`, you now can't name your variable tax, so you added an x onto the end. Instead, ***start all class names with a captial letter***, i.e. use `class Tax` instead of `class tax`. This will allow you to declare variables like so, `Tax tax = new Tax();`, which helps you avoid confusing names.

**Choose descriptive method names**

It's a good idea to name your methods based on what they do. In your `tax` class, your `double tax1()` method calculates the user's tax burden, so it might be a good idea to change the name of it to `double calculateTaxBurden()` instead.

**Avoid redundant variables**

Your `math` variable in your `double tax1()` method and in your `tax` class doesn't do anything, since you immediately return the value of it once you have assigned it. You should remove the `math` variable and just say `return income * taxrate;`. This will make it more obvious as to what is going on in your code, since you won't have confusing variables that don't do anything hanging around.

**Try to reduce code duplication**

Each one of your if statements shares the same line of code: `return math = income * taxrate;`. This isn't going to keep your code from working, but it would be nice if you could move that line out of the if statements. An example of why it's a better idea to avoid code duplication is when it comes time to change things. Now let's say that everybody get's a $2000 deduction from their income and a $200 tax credit. Currently, you would have to change 6 lines of code to implement those new rules. Instead, you should move shared code out of those if statements so that changes to the tax calculation only need to be made in one spot. In other words:

```
    taxrate = 0;
    income = scan.nextDouble();
    if(income <= 6000){
        taxrate = .10;
    }

    if(income >= 6001 && income <= 27950 ){
        taxrate = .15;
    }

    if(income >= 27951 && income <= 67700){
        taxrate = .27;
    }

    if(income >= 67701 && income <= 141250){
        taxrate = .30;
    }

    if(income >= 141251 && income <= 307050){
        taxrate = .35;
    }

    if(income >= 307051){
        taxrate = .386;
    }
    return income * taxrate;
```

It may not seem to matter right now, but keeping your code clean, simple and easy to maintain is a good habit to get into early on. It will save you a lot of effort when you start working on larger and larger projects.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help me with this assignment. It was very helpful. I did take your advice and kept my code clean. It looks much better. Thanks again!! -Vega-